# Show that a connected set contains a point on the line x = y

Tags: calculus

Let $S$ be a connected set. Show that $S$ contains at least one point on the line $x = y$.

I know what a connected set is, and I know you should probably use the function $f(x,y) = x- y$ and use the intermediate value theorem somehow but the fact that S is in $\mathbb{R}^2$
is what is throwing me off.

Comment: Hint: Argue by contradiction. Suppose not. What happens to $S$ if there are no points on that line?

Comment: @AlfredYerger i assume that it gets disconnected but how?

Comment: A space is disconnected if it can be split into two open/closed sets - if you remove the line $y=x$, can you find a way to divide up the remaining stuff in $S$ so as to find a contradiction?

Comment: Surely this is not true. The open upper left quadrant is a counterexample. Clearly everyone else is reading this problem differently than I am. What am I missing? The set U from the answers below is a connected set in the plane that does not intersect y = x.

Comment: @user4894 Sorry I went to edit the question but accidently deleted it, the original question was suppose that ($(1,3) and (4, -1) \in S$, show that S contains at least one point on the line $x = y$

Comment: @AlexChavez Thank you, that certainly makes a difference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U = \{ (x,y) | x < y \}, V = \{ (x,y) | x > y \}$. It is clear that both $U,V$ are open, non-empty and disjoint.

We have $(1,3) \in U$, $(4,-1) \in V$.

Now suppose $S$ does not intersect $D = \{ (x,x) \}_x$. Then $S \subset U \cup V$. This implies $S$ is non connected, hence a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ denote the line. If $S$ didn't meet $L$, then $S$ would be completely contained in the complement of $L$, which is the union of the top and bottom open half-planes $T$ and $B$, which are open in $\mathbb R^2$. $S$ meets both $T$ and $B$ since $(1,3)\in T$ and $(4,-1)\in B$. But then $\{S\cap T, S\cap B\}$ is a disconnection of $S$, contrary to the fact that $S$ is connected.